# Shortcut in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

Is there any shortcut for removing unused variables in Eclipse? Like how we remove unused imports? That shortcut will be really helpful while having huge lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the left of the code section, any unused variables will have a squiggly yellow underline and a small warning box in the errors/warning strip to the side. There is no keyboard shortcut, unfortunately.

Comment: If your Errors/Warnings preferences are set to report them.

Comment: @nitind that's true. But some things are presumed

Answer (score 1):

You can `Clean Up` function under `Source` menu.

For example, if you want to delete all variables which have `unused` warnings, you can do that like the following:

1. Open the Clean Up under the Source on menu bar.
2. Select `Use custom profile` radio button.
3. Select `Configure...` button on right side.
4. Select `Unnecessary Code` tab.
5. Tick `Remove unused private members`
6. OK and Finish

This is not the shortcut, but it might be helpful for you.